# How to use LINQ to query a complex XML document?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm new to working with XML and LINQ, but what I'm trying to achieve is converting this XML into a list of type 'product-lineitem' with two fields, one for net-price and one for the product-id.

So in C# this would be

```
List<ProductLineItem>
```

and a class like

```
public class ProductLineItem
{
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public decimal NetPrice {get;set;}
}
```

Here is a sample of the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <orders xmlns="xyz">
        <order order-no="00000605">
            <order-date>2016-04-25T13:45:14.133Z</order-date>
            <created-by>storefront</created-by>
            <original-order-no>00000605</original-order-no>
            <product-lineitems>
                <product-lineitem>
                    <net-price>57.75</net-price>
                    <product-id>3210</product-id>
                </product-lineitem>
                <product-lineitem>
                    <net-price>55.00</net-price>
                    <product-id>5543</product-id>
                </product-lineitem>
                <product-lineitem>
                    <net-price>57.75</net-price>
                    <product-id>4987</product-id>
                </product-lineitem>
            </product-lineitems>
        </order>
        <order order-no="00000622">
            ...
        </order>
        <order order-no="00000666">
            ...
        </order>
    </orders>
```

So ideally my end result would be grabbing each of these and creating a list of the class defined above

```
<product-lineitem>
    <net-price></gross-price>
    <product-id></product-id>
</product-lineitem>
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to implement a LINQ query for this. I've been playing with XElement and a StringBuilder but would like to have a List of objects instead of trying to manually build a string up like my code below.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(fileName);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.AppendLine(element.Attribute("order-no").Value);
foreach (XElement orderElement in root.Elements())
{
    result.AppendLine(orderElement.Attribute("order-no").Value);
    foreach(var item in orderElement.Element("product-lineitems").Elements())
        {
            var i = item.Element("product-id").Value;
        }
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple orders with the same `product-id`? Are you fine to keep them separate? If so, it sounds like you just need `root.Descendants("product-lineitem")` to select them all. It's not clear why you're doing anything with a `StringBuilder` though, or what the list would be *of* - have you defined a `LineItem` class somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the kind of thing you need:

```
var ns = XNamespace.Get("xyz");

var productLineItems =
    xd
        .Root
        .Descendants(ns + "product-lineitem")
        .Select(xe => new ProductLineItem()
        {
            ProductId = (int)xe.Element(ns + "product-id"),
            NetPrice = (decimal)xe.Element(ns + "net-price"),
        })
        .ToList();
```

With your sample data I get this:

[image: result]